# Error when using StaticResource

Tags: silverlight, static-resource

I'm getting this error

> Attribute {StaticResource
>   StoryboardIntroAnimation} value is out
>   of range

when I try and use a staic resource as the Storyboard property of a BeginStoryboard object.  The markup looks a little like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardIntroAnimation">
         ...
      </Storyboard>
   </UserControl.Resources>

   <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardIntroAnimation}" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>

   ...
</UserControl>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Set RoutedEvent on your EventTrigger ?

Comment: The default is the Loaded event (i think this is the only event supported in Silverlight) so you don't actually have to define it

Comment: Ah ok on Silverlight, i have the same issue, their are many bugs issue with Silverlight on Trigger. 

Do you have try with Behavior ?

http://www.c0ding.fr/2009/07/system-windows-interactivity-kesako/